# Drawing "opened count" over time given open-event and close-event documents

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have documents modeling the creation of a ticket, such as:

```
{
    "number": 12,
    "created_at": "2015-07-01T12:16:17Z",
    "closed_at": null,
    "state": "open"
}
```

At some point in the future, a second document models the closing event:

```
{
    "number": 12,
    "created_at": "2015-07-01T12:16:17Z",
    "closed_at": "2015-07-08T8:12:42Z",
    "state": "closed"
}
```

**Problem: I want to draw the history of opened tickets.** In the example above, I'd like ticket number 12 to contribute to the count on the whole `2015-07-01` to `2015-07-08` timespan. What I tried:

- Bucketing with `date_histogram` only seems to be able to give the number of tickets created or closed on any given date bucket.
- Scripted metrics only seem to allow me to change the metric computation, not the particular bucketing of a document.

This is my very first day playing with Elastic Search and Kibana so I might be missing something obvious. Especially, I cannot tell if buckets act as partitions (hence if a document can only be in a single bucket), and hence if my problem can only be solved by creating additional documents for each datapoint I want to appear on the graph.

Additional note: I have control over the feeding process and the schema if storing additional data can help, but I'd like to avoid doing so if possible.

Comment: Two things: do you want this in Kibana? Secondly: what buckets do you want defined (what are the limits for them)? You are talking about July 1st and July 8th, you chose these dates because these are the start and end days of a ticket?

Comment: Yes I want this in Kibana. The buckets I want the freedom to be per day, per week, or per month as date_histogram allows.

Comment: Create a document for each day.

Comment: @AlainCollins That's the answer I was fearing :-)

Comment: Or update the existing documents with an array of days/weeks for each day/week in which it stays open.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what you'd like to see your results, specifically regarding the concepts of "timespan" and "ticket count". For every single day, you'd like to know how many tickets were open that day, is that it?

Comment: @Val No, I want to know the number of opened tickets over time (that is, for each point in time, the number of tickets that are opened and not yet closed).

Comment: So in your example above, ticket number 12 should be taken into account on 07/01, 07/02, ... up until 07/07, but not 07/08 since the ticket was closed that day. Is that correct or am I still missing something?

Comment: Another question: why do you need to have two documents for this and not simply updating the `closed_at` and `state` fields of the existing one?

Comment: @Val Yes, this is correct for the ticket number example. If I update the document as you suggest, than I'm back to my question: how do I graph the number of opened ticket over time? What query do I write so that this document gets counted in on each date bucket (be it per day, per hour, ...)?

Answer (score -1):

Though thats not a big deal , either mantain Hashing on the basis of Dates, or keep the

> created_at

as a grouping key for documents made on a day , so that you can distinguish and query them as you want !!

Comment: Can you please explain with a full example? I don't understand your answer at all. Thanks.